# Counting words program in C omitting double spaces and punctuation

Tags: c

I am doing a course on the basics of C programming, I've been given a task to create a program that counts the number of words in a sentence, I've achieved this, however I have a secondary task to stop the program from counting punctuation, on top of this if i type in a consecutive space i need the program to ignore it, i don't know how to get round it. could anyone point me into the right direction, I am not looking for anyone to write the code for me.

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const char end = '.';
    int words = 1;
    printf("please enter a sentence: \n");
    char c = getchar();
    while (c != end)
    {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == ' ')
            words++;
    }
    printf("the total number of words is %d", words);
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: "_stop the program from counting punctuation_" -- But yours doesn't already! And `c` should be an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: If you remember the previous character, you can tell when a word starts and finishes. Instead of looking for spaces, look for letters.

Comment: one possible approach is to keep a 'status' variable that indicates if currently in a word or not.  If in a word, then a space delimits the word,  If not in a word, then ignore the space.  The status variable should be set true when any other character is read.  The status variable should be set false when a space is read.

Comment: the current algorithm has a logic flaw,  in reality, most of the time, a `.` ends a word, but that word will not be counted.

Comment: to get the program to keep the terminal open until the user enters another key,  the `getchar(); getchar();` will not reliability do the job:  instead use: `int ch; while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch); getchar();`

Answer (score 0):

Working from the code you give (i.e. counting words by finding delimiting spaces), you can solve the multiple spaces problem by remembering the last character ignoring subsequent spaces

```
    while (c != end)
    {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == ' ' && previous_c != ' ')
                words++;
        previous_c = c;
    }
```

Note though that if the user *begins* the input with a single space, then the program will still count this as one word. To prevent this you should initialse `previous_c` to some known value (e.g. `0`) and check for this case also. This means the `if` condition would become `(c == ' ' && (previous_c != ' ' || previous_c == 0))`

As Cool Guy commented, the program you've shown already ignores punctuation as-is.

As another improvement I would suggest looking at using a `do...while` loop instead of the `while` loop to reduce the places you need to call `getchar()`

Answer (score 0):

I would split it in 2 loops. One for skipping all non-word-chars and a second to skip the word-chars. Between these loops starts a word and will be counted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char c;
  int words = 0;
  printf("please enter a sentence: \n");
  for(;;) {
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF && !isalpha(c));
    if(c==EOF) break;
    words++;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF && isalpha(c));
    if(c==EOF) break;
  }
}
```